# MySQL Drop Constraint Syntax Error

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.1.36 I'm trying to drop a constraint named `chk1` but MySQL reports an syntactical  error. I looked it up but am unable to find it. What is the error?

```
mysql> create database house;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
mysql> use house;
Database changed
mysql> create table member(age integer);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> alter table member add constraint chk1 check(age>0);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> alter table member drop constraint chk1;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'constraint chk1' at line 1

mysql> alter table member drop check chk1;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'check chk1' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check constraint is parsed but ignored in Mysql. So you don't need to remove it. You can use enum or triggers to implement desired functionality. In your case you can also change `age` to `unsigned`.

Comment: Is there a way to force this constraint without using workarounds like enum or triggers?

Comment: In my understanding changing age to `int unsigned` or `SMALLINT unsigned` will do the job in this case. In same cases, `FOREIGN KEY` will work instead of enums. In general - no, you cannot enforce arbitrary check constraints

Comment: What would I do if I had a constraint like `check(age>40)` ?

Comment: I can see 2 ways : 1. Create before insert and before update triggers and raise an error if age is wrong. 2. If you can enumerate allowed ages (for example, if the field represents human age, it will have upper limit 200 years which is pretty optimistic). So you can create another table with all possible ages and add a foreign key to the old table.